# Using a value from Node function in Handlebarsjs helper

Tags: node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

My application passes some information from node/mongoose to a handlebars template. Part of this is a couple of functions, the results of which I use in the template and it shows up and works fine.

```
router.get("/output/:id", (req, res) => {
   Project.findOne({
      _id: req.params.id
   })
   .populate("user")
   .then(project => {
      if (req.user) {
         if (req.user.id == project.user._id) {
            res.render("projects/output", {
               project: project,
               inputTotal: function() {
                  // do some stuff
                  return inputSum;
               },
               outputTotal: function() {
                  // do some stuff
                  return outputCalcs.value; 
               }
            });
         } else {
            res.redirect("/");
         }
      } else {
         res.redirect("/");
      }
   });
});
```

I then have a handlebars helper function that I want to pass in the two returns as arguments

```
calc: function(firstReturn, secondReturn){
   let value = firstReturn + secondReturn; 
   return value; 
}
```

then in handlebars

```
{{calc inputTotal outputTotal}}
```

When I do this, it returns NaN, so I console logged the `typeof` of the function parameters and they're both functions, not numbers, which I suppose makes sense. How do I access them as numbers so I can use the values in my helper?

Comment: `let value = firstReturn() + secondReturn();` If they are both functions, you must call them to get the return value

Comment: @Profit that's it, thank you so much!